# jQuery enable Submit button only if all form fields has class before form submit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two forms in my bootstrap portal and by default both forms submit buttons are disabled.

I am validating all the forms input fields with `on('input', function () {}` and assigning `is-valid` class.

I am trying to enable the submit button if all the fields within a form has `is-valid` class with below jQuery function:

```
$forms = $("#form1, #form2");

$forms.each(function () {
  $formsInputs = $(this).find(".form-control");
  $formsInputs.each(function () {
    $(this).on('keyup', function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('is-valid')) {
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Submit buttons are enabling with the first form field gaining `is-valid` class without validating the rest of the form fields. How can I enable submit button only if all the form fields have `is-valid` class.

**Below the updated working code:**

```
   $forms = $("#form1, #form2");
            $formsInputs = $forms.find("input, select, textarea");
            $formsInputs.keyup(function () {
                if ($("#form1 .is-valid").length === 7) {
                    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                }
                if ($("#form2 .is-valid").length === 12) {
                    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually come at this from a different angle.

You have a fixed number of inputs per form, right?
Just match the number of inputs with the 'is-valid' class to the total number of inputs on the page.

```
if $('form1 input.is-valid').length == 12 {
 # enable the submit button
};

if $('form2 input.is-valid').length == 4 {
 # enable the submit button
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Used the above your code and updated the working code in my original question.